# Can't find html.tpl.php

Tags: 7, theming

I'm editing a template of the Seven theme in Drupal 7. I want to change something in the html.tpl.php file, but I can't find where it is located.

Where is it the html.tpl.php file used by the Seven theme? Does the Seven theme have a html.tpl.php file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is none.  To override it, copy `modules/system/html.tpl.php` into your Seven subtheme and change that.  Remember to clear cache to make your changes visible.

(Don't hack Seven directly, next core update will overwrite your changes.)

Comment: Thanks! I'm not hacking Seven directly I got a copy in my sites/all/themes folder!

Answer (score 0):

If it is not in your custom theme you can copy from modules/system/ html.tpl.php and change it

Comment: This answer may be correct but is very short, it should explain in more detail de issue. Also, the user that asked the question seems to be editing the Seven core theme (hacking core!), it would be nice to ask if it's doing this and tell him this must be avoided.